# I can't find the location of a file that my app creates in Android

Tags: android, xml, file

Hello my code has two buttons Save and Read when I press save it saves data to a SampleFile.xml  and when I press load the content of the xml file shows up in the screen of the device. My app working but when i am trying to locate the SampleFile.xml there is nowhere. I tried my app to emulator and to a physical device

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText inputText;
    TextView response;
    Button saveButton,readButton;

    private String filename = "SampleFile.xml";
    private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
    File myExternalFile;
    String myData = "<question> "+ Test.s +" <qusetion>\n";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myInputText);
        response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);



        saveButton =
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveExternalStorage);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new   FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
                    fos.write(myData.toString().getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                inputText.setText("");
                response.setText("SampleFile.xml saved to External   Storage..");
            }
        });

       readButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getExternalStorage);
        readButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new  FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                    BufferedReader br =
                            new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(in));
                    String strLine;
                    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        myData = myData + strLine;
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                inputText.setText(myData);
                response.setText("SampleFile.xml data retrieved from External Storage...");
            }
        });

       if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
            saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
        }


     }
        private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState))     {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

      private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are never initializing the `myExternalFile` variable.

Comment: Try printing with Log the path you use to store your file. Something like this: Log.d("PATH",new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename));

Comment: @lionscribe yes he is in this line: myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);

Comment: What happens when you run your app?

Comment: why don't you just set a breakpoint, and see the path in runtime? or just log the path?

Comment: ok I will try to log the path but when I search my device from the search bar that searches the entire device the file is nowhere so I am thinking if the file is never created but then if the file is not created how do I load the data

Comment: In addition to printing the stacktrace, you should also display a more obvious message in your app UI, either as a Toast or a dialog. I suspect that an error has occurred while you create the file. Please also answer my previous question.

Answer (score -1):

try to find your file in Android/data/data/your_package/MyFileStorage/SampleFile.xml

Comment: This path should not be hardcoded. Instead, the OP should use a `Resources` object to query the internal storage directory.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i don't tell him save file on this path. but his code save file on this path. He can find it here with his code

Comment: the directory of app appears in this path but its empty

Comment: If you are suggesting that the OP looks in this directory to find the file, you should say so explicitly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok i got it. Thank you